# Text string bound to an ObservableCollection through a Converter not updating on collection change

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection, ivalueconverter

I have a pretty straightforward IValueConverter that converts a `IList<string>` into a comma separated string of strings. Trouble is the collection (which is a ObservableCollection) is not attempting to update the text, I can tell because a debug point in the IValueConverter shows that is is not being called after the initial binding on load.

The converter (This part seems to work fine when actually called)

```
public class CollectionToCommaSeperatedString : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return parameter.ToString();
        if (((IList<string>)value).Count > 0)
            return String.Join(", ", ((IList<string>)value).ToArray()) ?? parameter.ToString();
        else
            return parameter.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

The bound element:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedChannels, ConverterParameter='(Click to select channels)', Converter={StaticResource CollectionToCommaSeperatedString}, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

The CB for the property:

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedChannels
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(SelectedChannelsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedChannelsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedChannelsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedChannels", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(ChannelSelector), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>()));
```

Comment: How exactly do you update `SelectedChannels`?

Comment: @Sinatr .Add()/.Remove() which "should" trigger the update, correct?

Comment: @Sinatr I known the CollectionChanged event is firing because I hooked it and added a console dump and that looks good.

Comment: CollectionChanged won't trigger that Binding.

Comment: I'd think what since you are binding to `Text` the binding is *ignoring* the `INotifyCollectionChanged`. You would have to go with *standard* procedure (subscribing to event).

Comment: @Clemens Unfortunate. What can I do?

Comment: Yea, I can handle it all in the CB, was hoping to avoid that for sake of cleanliness.

Comment: Easiest solution would be to assign a new collection to the SelectedChannels property. There would also not be any need to declare it as ObservableCollection (which you usually don't do anyway with dependency properties).

Comment: @Clemens Alternatively, is there a way to forcefully trigger the property changed event on the DP, since there is no PropertyChanged event to invoke?

Comment: In fact you don't need converter, use attached property to bind to collection as you do now in addition subscribing to that collection events and set `Text` of control.

Comment: No, there isn't. The value of the property is the collection instance, which doesn't actually change. It stays the same object, regardless whether you add or remove elements.

Comment: @Sinatr You should probably write that as an answer with an example.

Comment: @Clemens Even though the instance isnt changing, in classes the implement INotifyPropertyChanged (which since this is a user control I cannot implement) I could call `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PropertyName"))` and force bindings to update anyway. Does a similiar invocation not exist for DP's?

Comment: @Clemens It will if the event is forcefully invoked, I use this "cheat" pretty often. Bound elements rely on the invoker to check for equality, so if it is forcefully invoked bound elements assume a new value (even if there isnt one). But again, since im using a DP and inside a usercontrol class, I cannot implement INotify.

Comment: Nothing stops you from implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in a class that is derived from DependencyObject. The property wouldn't be bindable if it's not a dependency property, but otherwise there isn't any problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility to achieve wanted is to wrap converter logic into reusable behavior.

Here is one, it will work as your converter is supposed, but only with `TextBlock.Text`:

```
public static class Behaviors
{
    public static ObservableCollection<string> GetTest(DependencyObject obj) => (ObservableCollection<string>)obj.GetValue(TestProperty);
    public static void SetTest(DependencyObject obj, ObservableCollection<string> value) => obj.SetValue(TestProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Test", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(Behaviors), new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) =>
        {
            var textBlock = d as TextBlock;
            var collection = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<string>;
            collection.CollectionChanged += (s, a) => 
            {
                // put logic here
                textBlock.Text = ... ;
            };
        }));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<TextBlock local:Behaviors.Test="{Binding ...}" />
```

TODO: add null checks, unsubscribing (may lead to memory leakages if binding to persistent ViewModel properties), proper naming...